# Extend ObjC class without modifyng its .m nor .h ? JS prototype style?

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

Is it possible to add methods to an ObjC class without modifying its .h nor .m files?

In JavaScript, you can for instance add a method to a prototype from anywhere, take for instance adding a method to the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.stackOverflow = function(parameters);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use categories.

[The Objective-C Programming Language: Categories and Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)

Comment: Perfect! This looks exactly like what I need!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Objective-C category for this.

Check this link:
http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Here's an example taken from that link (note I didn't write this part)

---

For example, below I’ve defined a category that adds a method to the NSString class. The method reverseString adds the capability to all NSString objects to reverse the characters in the string.

```
@interface NSString (reverse)
-(NSString *) reverseString;
@end
```

As with the @interface declaration, the @implementation section changes only in that the category name is added to the definition. Below is the implementation of the interface defined above. Notice how in both cases I added (reverse) , which is the category name I assigned.

```
@implementation NSString (reverse)

-(NSString *) reverseString
{
// SNIP: implementation of reverse string
return reversedStr;
}

@end
```